# There is a race condition in this code?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition

I'm trying to grasp the concepts of multithreading programming, and I think I'm doing well, but then I've found the following code for a simple `echo` server:

http://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/part2/chap7/echo-thread.c

And I'm thinking that the code is wrong, because it uses the same `main` local variable to store the data socket for each incoming connection. In particular, Im concerned about this part of `main()`:

```
while (1)
{   int client, addr_size = sizeof(addr);
    pthread_t child;

    client = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addr_size);
    printf("Connected: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
    if ( pthread_create(&child, NULL, Child, &client) != 0 )
        perror("Thread creation");
    else
        pthread_detach(child);  /* disassociate from parent */
}
```

As far as I understand, the variable `client`, local to the `while` loop, is allocated at exactly the same address in each iteration of the loop. So, when the first client is accepted, the thread receives `&client`, and when the second client is accepted, the value of `client` is overwritten with the new data socket, and this can have side-effects in the thread which is already running on the first client.

Observing the code of the function `Child`, which is the service thread, I can see that the argument is copied into a local variable:

```
void* Child(void* arg)
{   char line[100];
    int bytes_read;
    int client = *(int *)arg;
    ...etc...
```

and probably the author thought that this copy allows him to later tamper with the main `client` variable, but IMHO this can cause a race condition. If a second client arrives while the first thread is copying this variable, the value copied can be corrupt.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. There are two obvious ways to fix this:

1. Pass `client` to the thread instead of `&client`.
2. Allocate a new integer on the heap and pass its address to the thread and let the thread free it when it's done with it.

Comment: in addition to this, `accept()` can fail. in that case `client` is not overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.

You can demonstrate that you're right by adding a long `sleep` before `int client = *(int*)arg;` and connecting to the server two times while the first client thread.